# Check All Not Disabled

Tags: jquery, checkbox, disabled-input

Researching on here I found code that checks if a checkbox is disabled and I am attempting to implement it into my code with no luck.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="file1" id="pdf1" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP01.dwg" disabled="disabled"/><label for="pdf1"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs"> PDF</button></label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="file2" id="pdf2" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP02.dwg" /><label for="pdf2"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs"> PDF</button></label><br />
```

JQuery:

```
function pdf(source) {
  $('input[name=pdffiles]').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).attr('disabled'))
      checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  };
};
```

When I click the checkbox that selects all, it still selects all. Here is the previously working code that selects all as well (before I made the above changes):

```
function pdf(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('pdffiles');
  for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
  }
}
```

The goal is to check only the checkboxes that are not disabled.

Also, incase this helps, here is the checkbox that is clicked that runs the code:

```
<input type="checkbox" onClick="pdf(this)" class = "hidden-xs hidden-sm">
```

Oh and also, I have tried .prop instead of .attr

The Fiddle code provided below works perfectly! But I don't understand why it is not applying to my code:

```
function pdf(source) {
$('.pdffiles').not(':disabled').prop('checked', source.checked);
```

};

And I didn't change anything else..

Something else must be enabling the select all, but I cannot figure out what in the code I am editing.

I marked this question as answered because the code provided works perfectly. Something else in my own code is causing the select all. The code I am working on isn't my own but instead a co-workers, so I will have to try to work with him on getting figuring that part out I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) with [disabled-selector](http://api.jquery.com/disabled-selector/) to exclude the disabled elements, also note that `pdffiles` is a class not name

```
function pdf(source) {
    $('input.pdffiles').not(':disabled').prop('checked', source.checked);
};
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8greaq3/)

Comment: Or similarly `.is(":enabled")`

Comment: That's weird, you're right, it is a class not a name. How is checking all then?

Comment: @Christine268 it is not actually working - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/y8greaq3/2/

Comment: It is though, when I click the checkbox to check all, all are checked. In my code I mean.

Comment: See edit for changes...the Fiddle code works but not when applied to my code. :(

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```js
$('.pdffiles').not(':disabled').prop('checked', true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="file1" id="pdf1" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP01.dwg" disabled="disabled"/><label for="pdf1"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs"> PDF</button></label><br />
<input type="checkbox" name="file2" id="pdf2" class = "pdffiles" value="101SP02.dwg" /><label for="pdf2"><button type = "button" class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm hidden-sm hidden-xs"> PDF</button></label><br />
```